# How to execute batch commands depending on user input as string

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

```
set /P id=Enter id:
echo %id%

if %id%=='a'
(
:: DO THINGS1
EXIT
)


if %id%=='b'
(
:: DO THINGS2
EXIT
)


else (
echo Input can be either a or b
)
```

But everytime I am running the file it is not performing any command further even though I am giving 'a' or 'b' as input, it asks for only till user input and exiting. Would appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Given your example, I would suggest this: 1:`@Choice /C ab /M "What is your ID"`, 2:`@If ErrorLevel 2 (Echo=Do things based upon B entry)Else Echo=Do things based upon A entry`

Comment: thanks. I was facing this problem of wrong execution for diffrent string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how I wrap both values either side of `=` in double quotes.

```
@echo off
set /P id=Enter id:
echo %id%

if "%id%"=="a" (
  :: DO THINGS1
  goto :eof
)

if "%id%"=="b" (
   :: DO THINGS2
   goto :eof
 ) else (
   echo Input can be either a or b
)
```

This typically compares values exactly. i.e something like this.

```
if "a"=="a"
```

Would match, because you have the exact either side, where you tried to match this:

```
if a=='a'
```